# User Control loaded Programatically with a DataPager doesn't Page

Tags: asp.net, listview, user-controls, datapager

I have an asp.net user control with a listview and a DataPager that work as expected if it's loaded statically from an aspx page the usua way.

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/TricksSummaryOneSubTypeUC.ascx" TagName="sub" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
...
<uc1:sub ID="skdlj" runat="server" TypeId="7" SubTypeId="706" />
```

But If load it dynamically in a PlaceHolde I lost the DataPager functionallity. On selecting a new page it refresh but without items. When debuging it seems not to be firing events.

```
TricksSummaryOneUC pageControl = (TricksSummaryOneUC)LoadControl("~/Controls/TricksSummaryOneSubTypeUC.ascx");
pageControl.TypeId = 7;
pageControl.SubTypeId = subcategory;
PHControl.Controls.Add(pageControl);
```

The DataList is using and ObjectContainerDataSource as data source.

Comment: At what point of the control lifecycle (on what event) do you add this pager to your control?

Comment: The control is loaded during the onLoad